# What's best way to get all NodieIds or all NodeAliasPaths API 7

Tags: c#, kentico

I collected NodeIds (22,000 of them) to List and passed them to

```
tree.SelectSingleNode(NodeID) // Kentico API7
```

Whether I use

```
tree.SelectSingleNode(NodeID)
```

or its equivalent for `NodeAliasPath`

```
tree.SelectSingleNode(CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, aliaspath, culture)
```

with both returning a node that allows manipulation of Node data, I get a out of
memory error on either line:

```
tree.SelectSingleNode(NodeID) 

tree.SelectSingleNode(CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, aliaspath, culture)
```

Is the error message due to the code or the environment?

Here's the error message:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x005228e7, on thread 0x5330. The error code is 0x80131623. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're getting the information correctly.  Problem is you simply have too many nodes and run out of memory when storing all that data in memory.  What I'd do is get the data and process it in batches.  If you're running a multi-tenancy environment, you might also specify a SiteID in your where clause.  You can also specify the columns you want to receive back or modify and this will also help with the amount data you're bringing back.

Comment: The site is not a multi-tenancy environment. There is one site that has 22,000 nodes. I collect NodeIds for 22,000 nodes with C# code and store them in a List. I then use the nodeId to get the ACLid so I can use the ACLid to clear the ACL of every document.  I have tried rewriting the code using SelectNodes instead of SelectSingleNode, but doesn't make a difference. I tried putting in Thread.sleep in a few places to let the program rest, but doesn;t make a difference. No matter what, I run out of memory. Would clearing the data cache help? Would increasing DB memory help?

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to process these in batches.  Throwing more memory at the server is only a temporary fix for bad code.  Also specify which columns you need when retrieving your data, this will also help with the amount of data you're returning.